# Class 'de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIcon' doesn't support property 'selectionEnd'

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I have been struggling for this error. Searching in the internet for a long time. But still no luck. It's for my capstone project and I can't even run the program nor can edit the Layout in Scene Builder.

I have tried re-installing the Scenebuilder application and re import jar files. (Almost try to import all fontAwesome jar files just to solve this).  Have been restarting my computer many times.

Here is one of the code which has errors in it.

```
 <FontAwesomeIcon fill="#757575" glyphStyleClass="" iconName="DESKTOP" selectionEnd="0" selectionFill="#fcfcfc" text="" wrappingWidth="17.0" />
```

the field

```
selectEnd and selectFill
```

have the same error code. (the one above)

Hoping that someone can help me.

For now. i have imported the

- jfoenix-8.0.8.jr
- fontawesomefx-8.1.jar
- fontawesomefx-8.8.jar
- fontawesomefx-8.9.jar
- fontawesomefx-commons-9.1.2.jar
- fontawesomefx-weathericons-2.0.10-9.1.2.jar

BTW. I am using application
- Netbeans 8.2
- SceneBuilder 11.0

Right now i can't open my SceneBuilder. Just WOW

If there is a link for a possible solution for his. I would really appreciate it if you can share it.

Comment: If you are on Java/JavaFX 8, stick to 8 versions for all the jars (i.e. `fontawesomefx-commons` should be 8.15) and also for Scene Builder, use 8.5.0 from [here](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download).

Comment: `WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.181
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
`
Here is my StackTrace sir. Thanks for the immediate replay. I am new at java so I don't really know what is my JavaFX version, but based from what is written in my stacktrace. I believe I have JavaFX 11 v. Or is it ?

Comment: Scene Builder 11 runs on Java 11, Scene Builder 8.5.0 runs on 8. NetBeans 8.2 is recommended for Java 8, it doesn't support Java 11. Which Java version do you want/need to use?

Comment: I have just googled how to now my Java Version. And it seems to it that I have **Java v8** installed. So maybe i should re install my Scene builder to 8.5. Though I am just wondering why did this error occur only after using Scene Builder 11 for almost 2 days now ?. Anyway. thank you so much for clarifying 

Answer (score 0):

Class de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIcon does not exit solution

I had the same issue, but after uninstalling my scene builder 11.x, and I downloaded scene builder 8.5.0, I imported an icon as i did when using scene builder 11.x, but i still had the same error(Class de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIcon does not exit), so what i deed, was to import the font-awesome jar that i was using into Netbeans IDE.That solved my problem.
In conclusion, i imported the font awesome jar in scene builder but i didn't import it into netbeans, so that was the error that i had.